# How do I show the standard output of my Rust program in the output window of VS Code?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

I am trying to show the standard output of my Rust program in the output window of VS Code.  Right now the output goes to an external command shell.  Could I do it with `OutputDebugString` somehow? The `terminal.integrated` user settings do not seem to do anything.

[image: vscode output window]

[image: User Settings]

Comment: ever figure this out?